# Laravel 5 session put/push/pull array

Tags: php, arrays, session, laravel-5

I am trying to push,delete or update some data into L5 session array.

My code:

```
$id   = $request->input('id');
$type = $request->input('type');
$removeEvent = $request->input('removeEvent');

if($request->session()->has('event')){
    $events = $request->session()->get('event');
    $request->session()->forget('event'); //forget and create new session
    for($i=0; $i<count($events['id']); $i++){
        if($events['id'][$i] == $id&& $events['type'][$i] == $type && $removeEvent == 'true'){ //delete 

        }elseif($events['id'][$i] == $id&& $events['type'][$i] != $type){ //update
            $request->session()->push('event.id', $events['id'][$i]);
            $request->session()->push('event.type', $type);
        }else{
            $request->session()->push('event.id', $id);
            $request->session()->push('event.type', $type);
        }
    }
}else{
    $request->session()->push('event.id', $id);
    $request->session()->push('event.type', $type);
}**

$request->session()->save();
```

When I am going to post id and type, if **id** is on session and **type** is different, I want to update it or removeEvent is true then delete, if it is not on session push it. So, do I have to search whole array or is there any quick way for these actions?

**Update**:
I did a quick way for this whole code.

```
$check = $request->session()->has('event.'.$id);
if ($check == 1 && $removeEvent == "true") {
        $request->session()->forget('event.'.$id);
} elseif ($check == 1){
    $request->session()->put('event.'.$id, $type);
} else {
    $request->session()->put('event', 
    array_add($event= $request->session()->get('event'), $id, $type));
}
```

Comment: Do you wanna keep 1 session that has an array of all the events and 1 session for each event?

Answer (score 0):

This how you can keep all your events in 1 session.

```
/* I'm using the event ID as keys for easy query.
   $events   = [
                   64543  => ['id' => 64543, 'type' => 'A'],
                   345345 => ['id' => 345345, 'type' => 'B']
               ];
*/

$id          = $request->input('id');
$type        = $request->input('type');
$removeEvent = $request->input('removeEvent', false); // false by default

$sessionkey = 'events';
$events = Session::get($sessionkey);

// Remove an event or add/update
if ($removeEvent)
    unset($events[$id]);
else
    $events[$id] = ['id' => $id, 'type' => $type];

Session::put($key, $events);
```